# How to properly include libssh in C

Tags: c, gcc, libssh

I am getting an error every time I try to compile my code with gcc on Ubuntu.

I installed libssh-dev by typing:

```
sudo apt-get install libssh-dev
```

and it installed just fine (No error messages)

The code I am trying to compile is:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define LIBSSH_STATIC 1
#include <libssh/libssh.h>

int main(void){
    int rc;
    int port = 21;
    char *pass = "password";

    ssh_session my_ssh_session = ssh_new();
    if(my_ssh_session == NULL){
        exit(-1);
    }

    ssh_options_set(my_ssh_session, SSH_OPTIONS_HOST, "localhost");
    ssh_options_set(my_ssh_session, SSH_OPTIONS_PORT, &port);
    ssh_options_set(my_ssh_session, SSH_OPTIONS_USER, "username");

    rc = ssh_connect(my_ssh_session);
    if(rc != SSH_OK){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error connecting to localhost: %s\n", ssh_get_error(my_ssh_session) );
        exit(-1);
    } 

    ssh_userauth_password(my_ssh_session, NULL, pass);

    ssh_disconnect(my_ssh_session);
    ssh_free(my_ssh_session);
}
```

When I try to compile the code the error message says:

```
user@neodym:~/Desktop/projects/ssh$ gcc -lssh ssh_client.c 
/tmp/ccGihId0.o: In function `main':
ssh_client.c:(.text+0x2a): undefined reference to `ssh_new'
ssh_client.c:(.text+0x57): undefined reference to `ssh_options_set'
ssh_client.c:(.text+0x6c): undefined reference to `ssh_options_set'
ssh_client.c:(.text+0x84): undefined reference to `ssh_options_set'
ssh_client.c:(.text+0x90): undefined reference to `ssh_connect'
ssh_client.c:(.text+0xa5): undefined reference to `ssh_get_error'
ssh_client.c:(.text+0xe2): undefined reference to `ssh_userauth_password'
ssh_client.c:(.text+0xee): undefined reference to `ssh_disconnect'
ssh_client.c:(.text+0xfa): undefined reference to `ssh_free'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I all ready googled but nothing has worked so far.

The libssh header files are getting installed at */usr/include/libssh/* so gcc should be able to find those.

Can you help me to fix this?

Comment: Are you trying to compile statically or compile at all? What if you remove the `#define LIBSSH_STATIC 1` ? What if you add the `-static` compiler option?

Comment: @Kamil Cuk It seems like nothing really changes when I remove the `#define LIBSSH_STATIC 1`. I only including it becouse the libssh API was advising to do so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to compile with:

```
gcc -c ssh_client.c
```

and then link with `ssh` library with:

```
gcc -o ssh_client ssh_client.o -lssh
```

Or in one step:

```
gcc -o ssh_client ssh_client.c -lssh
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked for me